# EJB implementing both local and remote interfaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to create an EJB component that will service requests from remote clients and in order to process those requests it will be invoking other remote EJBs which I will refer to as utility EJBs.

My idea was to define a remote interface and a bean that implements it as well as a local interface and bean.

The remote interface would expose the core business methods to the clients and the local interface would be a convenient way to group all the utility EJB calls needed to process clients' requests.

Another way to do it would be to invoke utility EJBs directly from the core business methods instead of via the local interface, but this is what I wanted to avoid by having a local interface.

Would it make more sense to have just one bean class implementing both local and remote interfaces or two separate beans, one implementing remote, the other implementing local? I'm sort of new to Java EE so I'm wondering if there's a best practice design pattern to follow here?

```
Public class EjbA implements RemoteA {

    //method exposed to remote clients
    public void placeOrder(ClientID clientID ProductID productID){

      if (getBLocal().checkClientId(ClientID clientID)){
          //proceed
          } //else reject
    }

Public class EjbB implements LocalB {

    public Boolean checkClientId (ClientID clientID){
          (getCRemote().checkId(clientID)
}

}
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand the question. A local interface is needed when you expose your business methods to local clients residing in same .ear but in different .jar or .war. If your client are all remote, there's no need of local interface. Also, from what I read, it seems like you intend to use local interface for calling other clients.

Comment: Well, my EJB is servicing remote clients but in order to process their requests I need to call some other remote EJBs and for that I wanted to create a local bean that will be called only from inside my application. I was wondering if I should have only one bean implementing both local and remote interfaces or two separate beans like in the example I added to my question.

Comment: You can implement remote and local interfaces in the same EJB and the container will inject it with the local one if it is accessible locally. Or you can specify the needed interface in the JNDI lookup after the bean name if the bean implements more then one interface. And you can use the `@EJB` annotation with the `beanInterface` parameter to specify the interface to use.

Comment: Ah ok...you want a local bean, not a local interface. In this case, it is advisable (to me) to have an EJB as a remote facade for clients, which in turn call a Local EJB where all your business rules reside. So, the scenario you want to avoid, is the most advisable :-)

Comment: So you advise structuring it like in the pseudo code example in my question? The scenario I want to avoid is having only the façade EJB with all the business logic in it. The other scenario I'm considering is having the façade EJB implement both a remote and a local interface so that it exposes a local and a remote view. Is that advisable?